# SCSS and direct nesting

Tags: css, sass

I'm stuck on this one. I know I have an ability to reach all the way outside of the nested operators to add a prefix class like:

```
.myEl {
    html.no-touch & {

    }
}
```

and that will output:

```
html.no-touch .myEl {}
```

but I'm wondering if there is a way to escape by only one level, rather than all of them. Given this sort of input:

```
.myEl {
    .myEl3 {
        .myEl2 {} /* direct parent operator goes here? */
    }
}
```

I would expect this sort of output:

```
.myEl1 .myEl2 .myEl3 {}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: That is the default behavior, what are you getting instead of that?

Comment: @SecondRikudo in my example .myEl2 is just a placeholder. What I really want there is a different operator.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you want to get. What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in SASS. You'd probably have to do something like this if you don't want to nest further (which I'm sure you already knew).

```
.myEl1 {
    .myEl3 {
        /* Base styles here */
    }
    .myEl2 .myEl3 {
        /* Specific styles here */
    }
}
```